# How to convert valueOf date back to date

Tags: javascript, date

In my program I pass a `clientId` of a `new Date.valueOf()` as a temporary Id and the server may or may not pass an Id back, if it passes an id back then it won't be a valid date.

I want to check if the id passed back is a valid date, how do I convert the valueOf a date back to a date to see if it is a valid date?

```js
var basicDate = document.getElementById("todaysDate");
var valueDate = document.getElementById("todaysDateValueOf");
var converted = document.getElementById("todaysDateValueOfConvertedBack");

basicDate.innerHTML = Date();//Tue Mar 06 2018 15:48:42 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
valueDate.innerHTML = new Date().valueOf();//1520376522243
converted.innerHTML = new Date(valueDate.innerHTML);//invalid date
```

```html
<div id="todaysDate"></div>
<div id="todaysDateValueOf"></div>
<div id="todaysDateValueOfConvertedBack"></div>
```

Comment: Simple: convert to Number using unary `+`, as in: `new Date(+valueDate.innerHTML)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the fact that you are placing your results into DOM elements, where the data is converted to strings. When you pull the data back out and try to pass it to the `Date()` constructor, it wants a number, but you are giving it the converted string. Convert the string to a number and it works.

A better way around this would be to store the dates in variables directly and then populate the DOM elements from the values in the variables. This allows you to use the variables directly (which will not have had their data converted to strings) when you need to do your `Date` work.

**FYI:**

- Using `Date()` and not `new Date()` in your first line of code can be
  an issue. When `Date` is called as a function rather than as a
  constructor, it returns a `String` representing the current time
  (UTC). However, when `Date` is called as part of a new expression, it
  is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.
- Don't use `.innerHTML` when you're not working with strings that
  don't contain HTML. `.textContent` is what to use to get raw text of
  an element. In fact, there is no need for elements to get in the way
  of this.

When you straighten these out, it works:

```js
var basicDate = document.getElementById("todaysDate");
var valueDate = document.getElementById("todaysDateValueOf");
var converted = document.getElementById("todaysDateValueOfConvertedBack");

// Get dates but assign directly to variables to avoid implicit conversions:
var currentDate = new Date();
var valueOfDate = currentDate.valueOf();
var reconstructedDate = new Date(valueOfDate);

basicDate.textContent = currentDate
valueDate.textContent = valueOfDate;
converted.textContent = new Date(valueOfDate);

console.log(currentDate);
console.log(valueOfDate);
console.log(reconstructedDate);
```

```html
<div id="todaysDate"></div>
<div id="todaysDateValueOf"></div>
<div id="todaysDateValueOfConvertedBack"></div>
```

Comment: That's a bit of a cheat, it's just because it got converted to a string, and the new date expects an int to allow it to parse. Since you just assigned it to a variable, the implicit conversion didn't occur. The OPs code is perfectly fine if he does `parseInt( valueDate.innerHTML) )`

Comment: I feel like I just got schooled in JS when I was just trying to give an example rather than pasting in my actual code, I see how it is working here, and the way I am writing this in my actual code is just like you have here but its not working for me. `if(new Date(cvmValue.ClientLineId) === "Invalid Date")` where
 `cvmValue.ClientLineId` would be the `valueDate ` in my question above with `==` its always an invalid date (true), with `===` its never true..

Comment: @Blindsyde Please edit the question to show the code you really do have.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Sorry, before the edit, I didn't read that at all, your edit makes it clearer ;) Hmm, that second edit spoils readability (I think the implicit + string to number conversion is something an uglification should do)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'll mark this answer as correct because it is still helpful, I will try to post a new question that shows my exact code if I can whip something up, I tried to parse my string to an int and it made a real date so parseInt wont work for what I am doing. we're talking a string date that looks like "1520376522243" which is a date and one that looks like "00k1k000002eeYSAAY" which is a salesforce id

Comment: @Icepickle Thank you for saying something about parseInt, that alone fixed my issue, instead of trying to convert back to a date I just ran parseint on the id, if its 0 then its a salesforce id, if its anything else than its the date string i passed. `if(parseInt(cvmValue.ClientLineId) === 0)`. Again thanks to both of you, your answers led me in the right direction.

Comment: The Date constructor doesn't necessarily want a number, it can take zero or more arguments of different types. The string returned by `Date()` is implementation dependent, it's not necessarily UTC and isn't in any browser I tested..